# I don't know whats wrong with my sql code. What can I do?

Tags: sql, error-handling, db2

this is my code :

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE DISPLAYTRANS (IN transNo VARCHAR(8))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
  BEGIN   
    
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 
    
    SELECT s.transNo, s.salesDate, p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit, sd.quantity
    FROM sales s
    LEFT JOIN salesdetail sd ON s.transNo = sd.transNo
    LEFT JOIN product p ON sd.prodCode = p.prodCode
    WHERE s.transNo = transNo
    ORDER BY 1; 
    OPEN c1;
       
  END;
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

and I'm having this error:

> A reference to column "TRANSNO" is ambiguous.. SQLCODE=-203,
> SQLSTATE=42702, DRIVER=4.32.28

I'm using db2 and doing this task: Formulate a stored procedure DISPLAYTRANS() that will display the corresponding sales transaction based on the transaction number passed. Display transaction number, sales date, product code, description, unit, quantity. Use TR000039 to test the output of your script.

Comment: It is wise to use a naming convention for arguments/parameters for routines. Using a naming convention allows separation of names and prevents silly mistakes. One convention is that all of the formal-parameters in a routine might have names like "p_transNo" instead of just "transNo", so that the readers of the code can immediately see in the routine-body that the parameter is being referenced. Use another naming convention for local variable, global variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on your Where Clause - `WHERE s.transNo = transNo` try to change it to `WHERE s.transNo = p.transNo`

Since transNo also exists on other table, SQL doesn't know on what table are you referring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a routine parameter in your query, and its name is equal to some column name, you must qualify it accordingly - by the routine name.
Try this:

```
WHERE s.transNo = DISPLAYTRANS.transNo
```